# I need to prevent the files that are on my drupal website from beeing downloaded from outside even when they're on public nodes

Tags: .htaccess, drupal

I've set this in a `.htaccess`

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://websiteip.fr/fonds-spe/document-indisponible
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from websiteip
allow from 127.0.0.1
allow from localhost
```

That `.htaccess` works : each time I'm trying to download a file via the "Apache" URL, I got the Error Document - that's ok.

BUT

with that, even Drupal can't access the files to display or play them (some are videos or sounds).

For example, on a node with an image in it, I got *This image failed to load.*

Any idea suggestion welcome

Answer (score 0):

Each client will have a different public IP ... .htaccess is not the way to accomplish this. You'd be better suited modifying Drupal (via module) . Keep in mind however, if it plays on the screen or through the speakers, it can be recorded /downloaded /etc.

Comment: Hi Jeff.In fact, the only client is Drupal itself trying to play videos, no ?
I mean, the error i get is from inside de the video player of drupal trying to launch the video file, for exemple.

Comment: Hi Jeff - ok I've understand what you mean - that's really a prob for me then ... :(

Answer (score 0):

We use the Private Upload module on our site to protect files from being downloaded.
http://drupal.org/project/private_upload